# Flyway sql server on windows xp with windows authentification

Tags: flyway

i work on windows xp, with sql server 2008 r2(Express) installed and jdk 7
i've tried flyway to migrate to a database with windows authentification but every time i run the migrate command this error message appear

```
GRAVE: L'environnement d'exÚcution Java (JRE, Java Runtime Environment) version 1.7 n'est pas pris en charge par ce pilote. Utilisez la bibliothÞque de classes sqljdbc4.jar, qui permet la prise en charge de JDBC 4.0.

ERROR: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: L'environnement d'exÚcution Java (JRE, Java Runtime Environment) version 1.7 n'est pas pris en charge par ce pilote. Utilisez la bibliothèque de classes sqljdbc4.jar, qui permet la prise en charge de JDBC 4.0.
```

What should i do?
I've already try flyway with oracle and mysql and it worksvery well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resolved**
I started to use jTDS instead of Microsoft JDBC driver
This is the url connection I used to connect to my local server with windows authentification

```
flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1434;databaseName=baseTest;integratedSecurity=true;
```

and for a distant server

```
flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://myserver/baseTest;instance=SQLEXPRESS;
```

the port is optional I advice you to not set it,that could generate errors if you don't know the correct port.
In my case I was trying with 1433 as a port (the default for sql server) but It was generating connection's errors every time I ran the command until i verified with the sql server configuration manager that the TCP/IP port was set at 1434 not 1433

and now it works very well 
Thanks